# Macbook Air 2013 with Visual Stuido 2012

Tags: macbook-air

I am considering purchasing a 13" MBA with 8GB and 256GB hard drive.  I would like to use this system for windows development using Visual Studio 2012.  I am planning on using VM Fusion so that I can have a virtual machine for Windows 8.  Could I get away with using a smaller hard drive - 128GB and still have enough room for just one VM?  The only application on that VM would be Visual Studio 2012 and Office Professional(unless I went with Pages, etc.) and the OS. I was thinking I could keep the project source in the cloud or on a USB stick for each client.

Comment: have you looked into lenovo think pad x1 touch? I use both the x1ct and MBP, but like my x1ct more for windows Dev.

Comment: I have considered it but I need the option to develop software for the Mac.

Comment: then your most cost effective solution is a Mac because you must run Mac OS on Mac hardware.

Comment: I have a 2012 13" MacBook Pro, running windows via parallels with visual studio 2010 and 2012 installed. It works for me.

Comment: What size HD and amount of memory?  I was hoping to reduce the cost, but glad to hear that it is possible.

Comment: Based on what people are saying I can get away with the MacBook Air with 8GB and 256GB HD but would be better off with the MacBook Pro, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through roughly the same issue with my 2010 MBP and VS2010. The only ways I was able to use VS2010 was by either BootCamp to dual boot Windows, or through a virtual machine. From my experience, there is no other way to develop with Visual Studio on a Mac. I prefered a virtual machine via VMWare, but that is strictly my opinion.

Comment: you can use virtual box for Mac, then install windows.

Comment: That is true. There are plenty of virtualization software out there that will allow you to run Windows. VMWare just seemed to work better and more efficiently to me.

Comment: I was thinking about using VMware Fusion.

Comment: I agree, there are only two ways, dual boot to windows with bootcamp and get great performance, but 1/2 the hard drive, or use a VM, and get 1/2 the performance.

Comment: @Craig I was/am very happy with VMware Fusion, and I tried several before settling on it.

Comment: @nycynik You are very correct, however with VMware Fusion, you have the option to boot a virtual machine from a hard drive, i.e. install Windows through BootCamp for when you need the power, and boot it through VMware when you need the convenience.

Comment: @bullrider can you tell me what setup you have?

Comment: @Craig I can sure give you what I remember off the top of my head (my Mac is at home). It's a 2010 MacBook Pro, 320? Gb HD, 4 Gb Ram, whatever the standard Intel processor for that model was, running latest version of Mountain Lion, dual booted with Windows 7 Pro via BootCamp. VMware Fusion 4, with the BootCamp partition as a virtual machine, when needed. I do my Windows dev in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @bullrider Would you recommend the Pro over the Air or do you think the Air will work just fine.  I am asking as this will be my first official Mac and I want to make sure I get the right one.

Comment: @Craig IMHO I love my Pro, but from what I have read about the new Air's they are pretty good. It's really going to come down to what your preferences are in a machine. The Pro is going to have more external ports than an Air, but the battery life of an Air tends to beat the Pro. The Pro is bigger than the Air It is really going to depend on your personal preferences when it comes down to it. Also, if I am not mistaken, the Air, starting out, is a little bit cheaper than the base line Pro.